# Stop chrome from auto styling input type=search

Tags: css, google-chrome

Is there anyway to prevent Chrome from styling the `input type=search`. I can style the input fine when it is a `input type=text` although once I change this to a HTML5 search it boxs all styles I have applied to the input.

**Type = text**

[image: text]

**Type = search**

[image: serach]

Updated answer with reset properties

```
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration  {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Just uploaded images showing what I mean

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try:

```
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Does it help?